# Beautiful custom iOS UIs

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

There are tons of books, tutorials, examples that explain how to create your more or less standard iPhone or iPad UI. But I cannot find any resources that deal with creating very custom and graphical UIs. Can anyone give me some references/links that would help me understand what is involved in creating something like http://webis.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Image.jpg ?

Comment: Question was very good and useful; infact it has been closed by genial SO mods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cocoacontrols.com is a good starting point for that.